# MYSQLi select / fetch into one array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I tried to return MYSQLi data into an array but it doesn't get into the form I want.

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM pricee 
ORDER BY idd ASC
SQL;


if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$price=$row['price'];


$tt=(array)$price;
$i=(array)$row['idd'];
$p=array_combine($i,$tt);
print_r($p);
}
```

This gives me $p in the following form

```
Array ( [1] => "0.99" ) Array ( [2] => "0.47" ) Array ( [3] => "0.49" )
```

But I need it in the following:

```
Array ( [1] => 0.99 [2] => 0.47 [3] => 0.49)
```

How can I convert it in that form?

Comment: So you want to convert strings to floating point numbers in PHP and combine them into a single array?

Comment: basically I need the values returned from the database in one (numbered) array (see above please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $p[$row['idd']] = $row['price'];
}
```

I don't know if it was intentional, but if you are also showing a string to float conversion, then:

```
    $p[$row['idd']] = (float)$row['price'];  // or use floatval()
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work. It returns the values in the following form: Array ( [0] => 0.49 ) Array ( [0] => 0.99 )  but it should be only one Array

Comment: No, the code I posted creates one array.  Remove any code you have and check.